# From PHP how to efficiently execute this search in SQL Server?

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a database structure something like the following:

```
Table A: PersonId, GroupId
Table B: GroupId, ParentGroupId
```

Given a `PersonId`, I want to find the Ids of all people in parent groups of that person's group.

First I select the `ParentGroupId` for the given `PersonId`, by joining with `B`. Then I do a while loop, selecting and recording the `PersonId` from `A` based on the `GroupId` returned in the previous search, and continue the loop by obtaining the next `ParentGroupId` from `B`.

Is this an efficient way to do this search, or is there an option that does not involve a while to "bubble up" in this manner?

(this is a simplified version of the actual scenario, changing the schema is not an option)

```
 $sql = 'SELECT ParentGroupID FROM A WHERE PersonId = ' . $id;
  $result = $db->query($sql);
  $row = $db->fetch_array($result); 
  $parent_group = $row['ParentGroupId'];

  if(!is_null($parent_group)) {

      $parent_ids = array();

      while($parent_group > 0) {
          //is there a way to do this where I retrieve all managers <= lvl 6 at once, so I don't have to loop in order to 'tier up'?
          $sql = 'SELECT ParentGroupID, PersonID
                  FROM B 
                  INNER JOIN A on ParentGroupID = A.GroupID 
                  WHERE  ParentGroupID = ' . $parent_group;

          $result = $db->query($sql);
          $row = $db->fetch_array($result); 
          $parent_group = $row['ParentGroupID'];
          $parent_ids[] = $row['PersonID'];
      }
  }
```

Comment: What makes yoo think that query is inefficient?

Comment: @Mihai doing another query for each pass through a loop is the definition of inefficient.

Comment: What you could do is compress the 2 queries into 1 with a LEFT or RIGHT JOIN and then check your values with WHERE IS NULL

Comment: The while loop will iterate as long as parent groups exist for the previous obtained ParentGroupID

Answer (score 1):

Combining your two queries into one would be more efficient:

```
$sql = 'SELECT ParentGroupID, PersonID
  FROM B 
  INNER JOIN A on ParentGroupID = A.GroupID 
  WHERE  ParentGroupID IN (
    SELECT ParentGroupID FROM A WHERE ParentGroupID > 0
    AND PersonId = ' . $id .')' ;
```

Comment: @Don'tPanic His code doesn't seem to be recursive, it just gets all people with the same parent groups as a users (if I'm reading correctly). From the question: "Given a PersonId, I want to find the Ids of all people in parent groups of that person's group."

Comment: Well, it 'recurses' up the parent group structure. A group has a parent, which has a parent, etc... and the code iterates, recording PersonIds, as long as a person's group has a parent.